# Navigation by goal with Hector Quadrotor

Tags: ros, gazebo, path-planning, 3d-navigation, hector-quadrotor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I'm making a ROS enable quadrotor. And I'm learning a little with Hector Quadrotor in Gazebo.

I can use pr2_teleop to control the quadrotor, but I don't know how navigate by goals or paths. I found a launch file in

> hector/hector_navigation/hector_exploration_node/launch/exploration_planner.launch

that sould works to this purpose. But when I try to launch it I receive the next error:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [hector_exploration_node/exploration_planner_node]: can't locate node [exploration_planner_node] in package [hector_exploration_node]
```

Are there any way to launch that file? Are there any way in that package to navigate by key point or to a goal?

Thank you so much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56996/navigation-by-goal-with-hector-quadrotor/) by [Iván](https://answers.ros.org/users/4348/iv%C3%A1n/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This indicates that the node hasn't been built yet. A

```
rosmake hector_exploration_node
```

should fix that error.

/edit: In response to your comment: There was a compile error in hector_exploration_planner from Feb 12th to Feb 16th, but it should be fixed now. If you update your repo and try again, it should work.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Iván](https://answers.ros.org/users/4348/iv%C3%A1n/) on 2013-03-04**:
I have already tried that, but it returns a failure.

[rosmake-6] Finished <<< hector_exploration_planner [FAIL] [ 3.98 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package hector_exploration_planner.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.

Complete log: http://goo.gl/KfHdg

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2013-03-04**:
Oh ok, I see. See my edit above.

**Comment by [Iván](https://answers.ros.org/users/4348/iv%C3%A1n/) on 2013-03-05**:
Ok, it works. Thank you!
But now it returns a message "Still waiting on map". So I try using "indoor_slam_gazebo.launch" as map. And then there are a lot of errors.

Because of that I would like change the question, do you know a simple rosrun file to say to the robot, "go from 0,0,0 to 1,1,1"?